# Text in Outlook adding extra spacing/padding or line-height issue

Tags: html, outlook, spacing

I'm trying to remove some extra padding which Outlook appears to be adding to my text.

This is what I have so far:

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

<tr>
<td class="text-center" style="color:#ffffff; font-family:'Open Sans',Arial,sans-serif; font-weight:700; letter-spacing: -6px; font-size:80px; line-height: 50px; text-align:center; "><span class="pink">HELLO</span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="text-center" style="color:#ffffff; font-family:'Open Sans',Arial,sans-serif; font-weight:700; letter-spacing: -3px; font-size:64px; line-height: 70px; text-align:center;">WORLD</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="text-center" style="color:#ffffff; font-family:'Open Sans',Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:600;  letter-spacing: -0.4px; font-size:12px; line-height: 10px; text-align:center;">THIS IS A TEST</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

This renders correctly in my browser:

[image]

But as you can see here Outlook appears to add extra padding/spacing above and below the text. Removing line-height completely doesn't appear to clear this either (although that does then create an issue in my browser)

[image]

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance.